# How to fix "Error When Run Nuxt SSR On Vercel"

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

Command failed with exit code 1: npx nuxt build --standalone --no-lock --config-file "nuxt.config.js" /vercel/path0

```
22:49:04.071    
22:49:04.071    135 packages are looking for funding
22:49:04.071      run `npm fund` for details
22:49:04.100    [info] Install devDependencies took: 15238.448308 ms
22:49:04.101    [log]  ----------------- Nuxt build ----------------- 
22:49:04.461    [log] Running nuxt build --standalone --no-lock --config-file "nuxt.config.js" /vercel/path0
22:49:07.093    node:internal/crypto/hash:71
22:49:07.093      this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
22:49:07.094                      ^
22:49:07.094
```

[image]

this is my dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.6.1",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder": "^0.22.1",
    "@webzlodimir/vue-bottom-sheet": "^1.3.0",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.2.2",
    "cookieparser": "^0.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.26.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "nuxt-tailvue": "^1.0.95",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-currency-input": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/postcss8": "^1.1.3",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  }
```

I have sam project with same config on package.json , and running well , but when create new project with ssr "nuxt start" command running i got the error .

Comment: Is it running Node v18? Also please share your package.json + nuxt config file.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your vercel.json to use version 0.23.0.
See sample code below.

```
 {
   "builds": [
      {
       "src": "nuxt.config.js",
        "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder@0.23.0",
        "config": {}
       }
    ]
 }
```

FYI: Not specifying a version for vercel builder defaults to 0.24.0 (At the time of posting) which I'm not too sure of but seems to be using node 18

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

Update your builds array in your vercel.json file to file following

```
   "builds": [
  {
    "src": "~/nuxt.config.js",
    "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder@0.23.0",
    "config": {
      "serverFiles": [" Your server path here e.g api/* "]
    }
  },
  {
    "src": "Your server path here e.g api/*.js",
    "use": "@vercel/node"
  }
],
```

Hope this helps